# WSO2 AM Error after upgrade 1.6.0 to 1.7.0

Tags: mysql, wso2, upgrade, wso2-api-manager

I have upgraded APIM 1.6.0 to 1.7.0, with MySQL, following this information.

[Readme.txt for migration](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/apimgt/1.7.0/modules/distribution/resources/migration-1.6.0_to_1.7.0/README.txt)

But when I login on Administration Console or in API Store, I don't see any API.
When I login on API Publisher, I see the APIs, but when click on any API, I see this error on console.
Any idea?

```
[2014-05-27 11:34:56,304] ERROR - APIProviderHostObject Error occurred while getting API information of the api- BUSOtro-1.0.0
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.getAPIForPublishing(APIUtil.java:437)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractAPIManager.getAPI(AbstractAPIManager.java:301)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.jsFunction_getAPI(APIProviderHostObject.java:1893)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c2._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/modules/api/list.jag:8)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c2.call(/publisher/modules/api/list.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_6(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:23)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_info.c0._c_anonymous_3(/publisher/site/blocks/item-info/block.jag:25)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_info.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-info/block.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_34(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag:223)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0.call(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_35(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag:286)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0.call(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_34(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag:218)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0.call(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_35(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag:283)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0.call(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_34(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag:218)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0.call(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_46(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag:448)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0.call(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.pages.c3._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/site/pages/item-info.jag:17)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.pages.c3.call(/publisher/site/pages/item-info.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.pages.c3._c_script_0(/publisher/site/pages/item-info.jag:10)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.pages.c3.call(/publisher/site/pages/item-info.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.pages.c3.call(/publisher/site/pages/item-info.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.pages.c3.exec(/publisher/site/pages/item-info.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:570)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:432)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doGet(JaggeryServlet.java:24)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[2014-05-27 11:34:56,312] ERROR - item-info:jag org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error occurred while getting API information of the api- BUSOtro-1.0.0
[2014-05-27 11:34:56,347] ERROR - RhinoEngine org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "name" from null (/publisher/site/themes/default/templates/item-info/template.jag#5)
[2014-05-27 11:34:56,348] ERROR - WebAppManager org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "name" from null (/publisher/site/themes/default/templates/item-info/template.jag#5)
org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "name" from null (/publisher/site/themes/default/templates/item-info/template.jag#5)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:575)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:432)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doGet(JaggeryServlet.java:24)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "name" from null (/publisher/site/themes/default/templates/item-info/template.jag#5)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3687)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3693)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3712)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.undefReadError(ScriptRuntime.java:3725)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1483)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.themes.default.templates.item_info.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/site/themes/default/templates/item-info/template.jag:5)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.themes.default.templates.item_info.c0.call(/publisher/site/themes/default/templates/item-info/template.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_32(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag:188)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0.call(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_48(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag:484)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0.call(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.themes.default.templates.layout.base.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/site/themes/default/templates/layout/base/template.jag:23)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.themes.default.templates.layout.base.c0.call(/publisher/site/themes/default/templates/layout/base/template.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_32(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag:188)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0.call(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_48(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag:484)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0.call(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.themes.default.templates.page.base.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/site/themes/default/templates/page/base/template.jag:104)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.themes.default.templates.page.base.c0.call(/publisher/site/themes/default/templates/page/base/template.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0._c_anonymous_46(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag:467)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.jagg.c0.call(/publisher/jagg/jagg.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.pages.c3._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/site/pages/item-info.jag:17)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.pages.c3.call(/publisher/site/pages/item-info.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.pages.c3._c_script_0(/publisher/site/pages/item-info.jag:10)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.pages.c3.call(/publisher/site/pages/item-info.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.pages.c3.call(/publisher/site/pages/item-info.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.pages.c3.exec(/publisher/site/pages/item-info.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:570)
        ... 35 more
[2014-05-27 11:34:56,353] ERROR - ApplicationDispatcher Servlet.service() for servlet JaggeryServlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:451)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:438)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doGet(JaggeryServlet.java:24)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[2014-05-27 11:34:56,354] ERROR - StandardWrapperValve Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/publisher] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:451)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:438)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doGet(JaggeryServlet.java:24)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Have you tried to re-run that latest swagger resource migration script?

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue in swagger resource migration script and it was fixed in the latest patch.

Please use the scripts from following location : https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/apimgt/1.8.0/modules/distribution/resources/migration-1.6.0_to_1.7.0/

**UPDATE**

Link updated with renamed location.